# sorting rating by a unique filter using backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a collection of items in backbone.js which one of it's attributes is "rating" ( the rating can be between 1 and 5)

I would like to filter the collection that the items which are first are with the rating "3" then "3.5" and so on up to "5" and afterwards "2,5", "2" down to "1".

I have managed to filter by rating and get it sorted from 1 to 5 and then spliced the sorted collection but that's as far as I got.

I wonder if there is a quick way in backbone/underscore to do so rather then do the following:

1. sort the collection from 1 to 5.
2. split the collection to 2 arrays (one will have items with rating of 3-5 and the second with the rating of 1-2)
3. reverse the second array
4. merge the first and the second arrays together

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try defining a `sort` function on the [comparator property](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) of the collection.

Try this:

```
var sort = function(a, b) {
    // Sort normally if both >= 3
    if (a >= 3 && b >= 3) {
        return a - b;
    // Sort in reverse if both < 3
    } else if (a < 3 && b < 3) {
        return b - a;
    // Keep values less than 3 after those >= 3
    } else if (a < 3 && b >= 3) {
        return 1;
    // Otherwise a is >= 3 and b < 3, so a comes before
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

See [demo](http://repl.it/Ohn/1).

Except you would replace a and b with the actual attribute since the arguments will be objects instead of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I'll admit this is an odd use-case, but I guess if you want to do all of the sorting work in a single pass, I would use the underscore sortBy() method.  Assuming your collection contains models with a rating attribute do something like this:

```
_.sortBy(array, function(model) {
    var rating = model.get('rating');
    if (rating >= 3) {
        return rating;
    } else {
        return (rating * -1) + 10;
    }
});
```

Check out the documentation at http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy

Good luck!

Comment: By the way, if you've chosen to use lodash instead of underscore for Backbone, check out the docs here: http://lodash.com/docs#sortBy